# How to get paragraph and Indent from MySQL to php?

Tags: php, mysql

I manually inserted the text into the MySQL column called text with indented lines and returns. When I use the MySQL select all and echo the entry the returns are missing and it’s just one line.

Comment: How are you displaying the data afterwards? Remember that HTML takes no notice of such things. If you need more help, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing sample data as stored in the DB, and then the code you are using to fetch it and display it, and tell us what environment it's being displayed in (e.g. web page, console, text file or whatever).

Comment: I’ll update the question with the echo html. I didn’t see the question here before. I also get a question mark symbol on the output.

Comment: `I also get a question mark symbol on the output` ...maybe see this guide to help with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through